# Storm Trident and Spark Streaming: distributed batch locking

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-storm, trident

After doing lots of reading and building a POC we are still unsure as to whether Storm Trident or Spark Streaming can handle our use case:

- We have an inbound stream of sensor data for millions of devices (which have unique identifiers).
- We need to perform aggregation of this stream on a per device level. The aggregation will read data that has already been processed (and persisted) in previous batches.
- Key point: When we process data for a particular device we need to ensure that no other processes are processing data for that particular device. This is because the outcome of our processing will affect the downstream processing for that device. Effectively we need a distributed lock.
- In addition the event device data needs to be processed in the order that the events occurred.

Essentially we can’t have two batches for the same device being processed at the same time.

Can trident/spark streaming handle our use case?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: @Matthias J. Sax : Did you get answer by yourself ? If yes , which one you have selected Trident or Spark Streaming and why?

Comment: I did not ask the question...

Comment: you can dispatch the data into different partition with hash function to make same devices' data in the same process.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have unique id's, can you divide them up? Simply divide the id by 10, for example, and depending on the remainder, send them to different processing boxes? This should also take care making sure each device's events are processed in order, as they will be sent to the same box. I believe Storm/Trident allows you to guarantee in-order processing. Not sure about Spark, but I would be surprised if they don't.

Pretty awesome problem to solve, I have to say though.